# Sidebars fill up all available space

Tags: html, css

I've searched for this everywhere but I can't seem to find a solution; maybe it's just easy as hell but I don't see it. I have a banner across the top of my page with a logo in the middle. On the left and the right of this logo, I need two (different) x-repeating background images. Like so:

```
<div class="banner_container">
  <div class="banner_right"></div>
  <div class="banner_logo"></div>
  <div class="banner_left"></div>
</div>
```

All the style I know in advance is the following:

```
div.banner_container {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}
div.banner_right {
  height: 60px;
  float:right;
  background: url(img/banner_right.png) repeat; /* This is a  */
}
div.banner_left {
  height: 60px;
  float:left;
  background: url(img/banner_left.png) repeat;
}
div.banner_logo {
  height: 60px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: url(img/banner.png) no-repeat center;
}
```

I need the logo to go in the center and the left and right portions to fill up all remaining space left and right. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to point out another solution, using position absolute http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/yVhsY/, since I generally dislike using float.

There are multiple ways to handle this kind of request.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this be an acceptable solution for your needs?
http://jsfiddle.net/8BqH4/

I only tested it on Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 10 on Mac.

Comment: well there's a bit of content beneath the logo (which also has a fixed width, like 900px) that's also centered, so if I force a sidebar's width (the 20% you used), the logo and the content won't be aligned anymore right?

Comment: Check my example, it uses and outer_logo div, that acts as an overlay over the sidebars.

Comment: I agree, Khez solution is probably better if you need to have the content bellow horizontally aligned with the header without implementing the same column layout.